# SELECT multiple columns with conditions from a table that contains only one VALUE column and two counters (X,Y)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, and i want to be able to select 3 different columns from one and only Table column  (DATA) (under certain conditions)

Here is the Initial Table MYTABLE that i want to exploit :

```
    Table_id   X   Y   DATA
    22         0   0   DEV
    22         0   1   TRAD
    22         1   0   5
    22         1   1   2
    22         2   0   300
    22         2   1   100
```

The result that i want to have is the following :

```
COL1    COL2   COL3
DEV     5      300
TRAD    2      100
```

and my 3 distinct SQL queries are as follow :

```
SELECT t1.DATA as "COL1" from MYTABLE t1 where t1.Table_id = 22 AND t1.X = 0
```

GIVES THE FOLLOWING RESULT  :

> ```
> COL1    
> DEV     
> TRAD
> ```

```
SELECT t2.DATA as "COL2" from MYTABLE t2 where t2.Table_id = 22 AND t2.X = 1
```

GIVES THE FOLLOWING RESULT  :

> ```
> COL2    
> 5
> 2
> ```

```
SELECT t3.DATA as "COL3" from MYTABLE t3 where t3.Table_id = 22 AND t3.X = 2
```

GIVES THE FOLLOWING RESULT  :

> ```
> COL3    
> 300
> 100
> ```

Can anyone please help me to merge those 3 queries into one and select the 3 columns from the DATA column ?

Comment: You should join this three data sets. But since there is no row order in SQL (since the data is an unordered set), you need to number your rows and join on that row number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when x = 0 then data end) as col1,
       max(case when x = 1 then data end) as col2,
       max(case when x = 2 then data end) as col3
from mytable
where table_id = 22
group by y
```